# Replace row values in dataframe that meet special conditions

Tags: r

I need to replace the 0's with 1's, but only where groups of values meet the following conditions; "1 0 1" or "0 1" (if at the beginning) or "1 0" (if at the end). Given the example dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1),
                 b = c(1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1),
                 c = c(1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1),
                 d = c(1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                 e = c(1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                 f = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1))
df
```

It would need to return this :

```
df.result <- data.frame(a = c(1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1),
                        b = c(1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1),
                        c = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1),
                        d = c(1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                        e = c(1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                        f = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
df.result
```

Notice that the relevant 0's have changed to 1's. Essentially, I'm trying to replace all the 0's that occur alone in a row.

Any idea how to achieve this in R?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `rollapply()` from the package `zoo` could be useful for each row. ... or `rle()` from `base`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `rle()`:

```
foo <- function(x) {
  r <- rle(x)
  r$values[r$values==0 & r$lengths==1] <- 1
  inverse.rle(r)
}
foo(c(0,1,0,0,1,0,1))  # testing the working horse:
# [1] 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
```

now apply this function on each row and give the result the desired form. `apply()` coerces its first argument to a matrix:

```
t(apply(df, 1, foo))
# > t(apply(df,1,foo))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1
# [2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1
# [3,]    1    1    1    1    1    1
# [4,]    0    0    1    0    0    1
# [5,]    1    1    1    1    1    1
# [6,]    1    1    1    1    1    1
# [7,]    1    1    1    1    1    1
# [8,]    0    0    0    1    1    1
# [9,]    1    1    1    1    1    1
# [10,]   1    1    1    1    1    1
# [11,]   1    1    1    1    1    1
```

If you want a dataframe as result you can do:

```
df.result <- df
df.result[,] <- t(apply(df,1,foo))
```

Comment: Thanks! What a nice solution.